# how to stuff a byte in an AnsiChar?

Tags: delphi, freepascal

Due to the incertitude about the data nature we began to read some bcd values to Chars.
For example if the data in the file is 6 bytes long so we would read it like that:

```
var
  fifi     : TextFile;
  path, res: AnsiString;
  i        : Integer;
  tmp      : AnsiChar;
begin
  assignFile(fifi, path);
  reset(fifi);
  for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
   read(fifi, tmp);
   res := res + tmp;
  end;
end.
```

As it is binary data doing a cast on each chars gives us back the data.

This is something that would be hard to change now.

I now have a custom made function that construct signed packed bcd values from a string in the form of an array of bytes.

I then would like to do the opposite which is stuff each bytes of this array in an AnsiChar so that we could merge it with the ebcdic data produced earlier in the process.

But what the read function does naturaly, is hard to reproduce. There is always some corruption or implicit conversion that is being done from what I constated.

Here is what I tryed :

```
function memoryStreamToString(str: TMemoryStream): AnsiString;
  begin
    setString(result, PChar(str.memory), str.size div sizeOf(AnsiChar));
  end;

function byteToStr(t: array of Byte): AnsiString;
  const
    digits: array[0..15] of AnsiChar =
      ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
  var
    i: Integer;
  begin
    result := '';
    for i := low(t) to high(t) do
      result := result + digits[(t[i] shr 4) and $0F] + digits[t[i] and $0F];
  end;

var
   buff                 : array of Byte;
   bcdlen               : Integer;
   res                  : AnsiString;
   //str                : TMemoryStream;

begin

  //code that init res, buff

  // way number one
  //str := TMemoryStream.Create;
  //str.writeBuffer(buff[0], bcdLen);
  //res := memoryStreamToString(str);
  //str.free;

  //way number two
  //res := byteToStr(buff);

  // way number three
  //setLength(res, bcdLen);
  //move(buff[0], res[1], bcdLen);

end.
```

So the question I think is How do you stuff a byte in an AnsiChar without corruption?
I believe it is not good practice to do it as the nature of the data is not respected but but we are too late in the implementation phase to change it.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you writing code for both Delphi and FPC?

Comment: I use fpc at home so I am making the code compatible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be any corruption unless you perform string conversion operations. Put a byte into an `AnsiString` like this:

```
str[i] := Chr(b); // I am assuming you are on a pre-Unicode Delphi
```

Or you can use a cast:

```
str[i] := AnsiChar(b);
```

That puts a single byte into an element of a pre-allocated `AnsiString`. In the opposite direction you write:

```
b := ord(str[i]);
```

If you want to blit a byte array onto a string then use:

```
SetLength(str, count);
Move(buff, Pointer(str)^, count);
```

This code is the same as your third method. It works just fine and there will be no corruption, unless you perform some subsequent operation on the string. Your first method will also work but is over-complicated. Your second method does something completely different involving hexadecimal representation. I'm not quite sure what you were trying to achieve there.

But you really want to be using byte arrays rather than strings. A dynamic array of byte, `array of Byte` is your guy.

Comment: The cast does not seem to be working but I reused the third method as you mentionned and after tests it seems to work. Maybe I missed it before. As for the seconf method I am not the author. Thanks

Comment: Also I have support for unicode but the data I am handling is legacy

Comment: I honestly cannot see how the cast can fail